# Сочинение

Tags: литература

Помогите пожалуйста с идеей, для написания сочинения на тему: "Добро и зло в романе Булгакова "Мастер и Маргарита"

Может план для написания

Comment: А самой подумать - не судьба? Не научитесь думать сейчас, так и останетесь без мозгов на всю жизнь.  
Ничего сложного в этой теме нет для того, у кого есть хотя бы одна извилина.  
К тому же, тут не делают школьные задания. Напишите сочинение САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО, а мы можем поправить.

Comment: Лучше бы  ничего не писал, раздражают подобные сообщения, к тому же я не просила писать готовое

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki,ну зачем Вы так?  "...так и останетесь без мозгов на всю жизнь...","Ничего сложного в этой теме нет для того, у кого есть хотя бы одна извилина". Даже для технаря такая грубость не простительна, а уж Ва-ам... Ей-Богу, некрасиво!

Comment: Возможно, что тема Добра и Зла вообще для нас непостижима. Мы находимся внутри закрытой системы, а эта тема глобально определяется вне ее. Мы же можем решать только мелкие частные задачи, да и то с помощью аксиом местного значения(смайлик).

Comment: @русак по-вашему все технари грубые?

Answer (score 1):

Ознакомьтесь с монографией "РОМАН МИХАИЛА БУЛГАКОВА «МАСТЕР И МАРГАРИТА»: АЛЬТЕРНАТИВНОЕ ПРОЧТЕНИЕ". В соответствии с теорией, построенной ее автором А. Барковым, "Мастер и Маргарита" - роман вовсе не о Добре и Зле. Впрочем, можете прочитать и любое другое исследование - сразу обогатитесь идеями для сочинения. Вышеозначенное я Вам рекомендую как содержащее наиболее аргументированный и убедительный, на мой взгляд, анализ романа.
Находится оно здесь: http://m-bulgakov.narod.ru/master-94.htm

Answer (score 0):

Почему сюда обратились , а не на сайты с готовыми сочинениями? Вот там и ищите идеи. Прочитав чужие, создайте свою. Вот, например:

http://www.litra.ru/composition/get/coid/00068501184864074468/woid/00055401184773069794/
http://www.vsekratko.ru/sochinenie/bulgakov/master_i_margarita_31/
http://school-essay.ru/dobro-i-zlo-v-romane-bulgakova-master-i-margarita.html
http://www.ymnik.ru/page.php?page=771&subs=302

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя ли перечислить уже существующие идеи по теме добра и зла - высказанные в романе (с точки зрения критиков) или обозначенные в философских сочинениях.  Тогда мы, может быть,  добавим что-нибудь новенькое. (Это пожелание для всего  форума).

Автор вопроса тоже может принять участие - в конце концов, у каждого есть мнение на этот счет. Тогда свое личную идею вы можете поискать в романе, а мы вам в этом поможем (надеюсь, что поможем).